# jQuery: Is there a menu plugin that does what I'm looking for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm building an AJAX app. I've got several menus, where there is a list of possible options (provided by the server). The user can choose or unchoose any of those values. When the user makes a choice, it is saved to the server.

So if the total list is `[A, B, C, D]`, it might look something like this:

```
User has chosen:
-A [Delete]
-B [Delete]

Unchosen (in a dropdown menu):
-C [Add]
-D [Add]
```

Then if the user chooses `C`, it would look like:

```
User has chosen:
-A [Delete]
-B [Delete]
-C [Delete]

Unchosen (in a dropdown menu):
-D [Add]
```

`C` is removed from the list of choices, and added to what the user has chosen.

Is there a plugin that does this, or should I roll my own?

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen a plugin to do exactly that. You could look at something like this [multiselect](http://www.senamion.com/blog/jmultiselect2side.html) plugin to give similar functionality.

It would not take long to roll this however.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would take you longer to learn the plugin then to write your own script.  Plus I think you would want to write your own for the customization factor alone.